# How to use window functions?

Tags: r, window-functions

I'm struggling to get window functions working in R to rank groups by the number of rows.

Here's my sample code:

```
data <- read_csv("https://dq-content.s3.amazonaws.com/498/book_reviews.csv")

data %>% 
    group_by(state) %>%
    mutate(num_books = n(),
           state_rank = dense_rank(num_books)) %>% 
    arrange(num_books)
```

The expected output is that the original data will have a new column that tells me the rank for each row (book, state, price and review) depending on whether that row is for a state with the most book reviews (would have state_rank of 1); second most books (rank 2), etc.

**Manually I can get the output like this:**

```
data <- read_csv("https://dq-content.s3.amazonaws.com/498/book_reviews.csv")

manual_ranks <- data %>% 
  count(state) %>% 
  mutate(state_rank = rank(1/n))

desired_output <- data %>% 
  left_join(manual_ranks) %>% 
  arrange(state_rank)

sample_n(desired_output, 10)
```

In other words, I want the last column of this table:

```
 data %>% 
 count(state) %>% 
 mutate(state_rank = rank(1/n))
```

added to each row of the original table (without having to create this table and then using `left_join` by state; that's the point of window functions).

Anyway, with the original code, you'll see that all state_rank just say 1, when I would expect states with the most book reviews to be ranked 1, second most reviews would have 2, etc.

My goal is to then be able to filter by, say, `state_rank > 4`. That is, I want to keep all the rows in the original data for top 4 states with the most book reviews.

Comment: I think you need `summarise`, not `mutate`.  That will give you one row per `state`.  If not, please make your question *reproducible* by providing both test input data and expected output.  `head(4)` may be a cleaner way of getting your top 4, rather than `filter(row_number() <= 4)` or similar.

Comment: @Limey: Added. The point of window functions is to avoid changing the structure of the data (which summarise) does. See an example image here: https://rb.gy/zsyvox from https://towardsdatascience.com/sql-ranking-window-function-guide-b9aee35d5931

Comment: In that example they ranked cities within each state, whereas I want to rank states within the entire data set.

Comment: You've said "added" but the example input/output data is not showing up for me - is the edit still pending?

Comment: Your sample code does *not* "change the structure of the data" since you don't assign the result to an object, let alone overwrite the original  `data`.  As @PaulStaffordAllen writes, your edit is not yet visible to me.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen, sorry, just added.

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with your "manual" solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite get why you would like to rank on number of reviews per state without also grouping by title and perhaps giving some weight to price, but by your original description:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- read_csv("https://dq-content.s3.amazonaws.com/498/book_reviews.csv")

data_ranked <- data %>%
    group_by(state) %>% 
    mutate(reviews = sum(!is.na(review) == TRUE)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    mutate(state_rank = dense_rank(1/reviews), .keep = "unused")
```

This will let you filter your data by states with the most or fewest total reviews. Notice that I drop the column `reviews`, but if you want to keep it, just remove the `.keep = "unused"`.

edit: I originally forgot to reverse the rank so that the state with the most reviews have the highest rank (as the rank function ranks the numerical values from low to high). Making it a fraction of 1 is the simplest way I could think of.

Also, counting the number of reviews per group exploits the fact that a logical `TRUE` equals 1 in R. I assume you only want to count the reviews that does NOT have a `NA` value. I would definitely want to weigh the reviews by converting them to a scale - so that a book with only `poor` reviews is not a good thing on a state ranking.

Comment: Oh, and the rank can be reversed by doing `dense_rank(1/reviews)`, to make the ranking following a decreasing number of reviews

Comment: I kept the review column and noticed the total didn't add up to the numbers I'm seeing. Basically the number of reviews should equal the `n` from this table ` data %>% 
 count(state) %>% 
 mutate(state_rank = rank(1/n))`. Unless I'm missing something? I.e., running `data %>% 
  filter(state == "New York")` , you can see that New York has 272 rows, but if I remove the `.keep = "unused"` , your table shows that New York has 250 rows.

Comment: @Khashir: Yes, as I comment, and which is visible in the code is that I exclude all reviews that have the value 'NA' in the column `review`. Otherwise, you can - instead of the `mutate(reviews = sum(!is.na(review == TRUE))` line do `mutate(reviews = n())`.

Comment: Ah missed that--thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

First, let me say, that there are at least two problems with your "manual method", so I'm not 100% percent sure I understood the question right.

Problem 1: You compute ranks with:

```
manual_ranks <- data %>% 
  count(state) %>% 
  mutate(state_rank = rank(state))
```

The expression `rank(state)` operates on the `state` column, so on the **names** of the states. Meaning the state whose name comes first in the alphabet gets the lowest rank. You probably want to compute rank by book count, so you would need `mutate(state_rank = rank(n))`.

Problem 2: Statistical ranks are per definition non-decreasing with value, so the state with the **lowest** counts gets rank 1. (You can of course easily transform the result; I just wanted to point out that the code's output does not fit your description.

Now on to your question:

You are right that window functions don't change the shape of data (to be precise, they do not change the number of rows in the data), but their limitation is that **they can only operate on the data of the current window**. You want to compute the ranks of the book counts of different states. Since every state forms its own group/window, **this is an operation involving different groups/windows**. You simply cannot solve this with window functions.

If you want to avoid the use of the helper table and the join, you can use `nest` to collect the books for each state in one row and restore everything with `unnest` after the rank calculation. This way everything can be done in one pipe:

```
data %>% 
  nest(books = c(-state)) %>% 
  mutate(state_rank = dense_rank(map_dbl(books, ~1/nrow(.)))) %>% 
  unnest(books)
```

(Note that I adress Problem 2 by computing the rank on `1/#reviews` such that the state with the highest number of reviews gets the lowest rank, i.e. 1)

Personally, I would however prefer the "manual method" you have outlined, as I find it to be much clearer than the alternative with `nest()`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer--def works with the sample data! I'll take a swing with the actual data. What is `map_dbl` doing in this code?

Comment: Also while not directly relevant to the question, I think your outline of Problems 1 and 2 can be confusing to readers--the code I provided for the manual approach definitely works (I've added the full pipeline so you can copy and test--I just did again just to be safe), so the answer would be better with that removed.

Comment: Either your manual approach does not work, or my solution does not work - they give different results! I'm fairly certain that `mutate(state_rank = rank(state))` (what you have written) is not what you want - it is a completely meaningless operation that does not depend on the result of the `count(state)` operation.

Comment: You're right, I missed that NY was the state with the most rows and so should be first or last (depending on whether I used `rank(n)` or `rank(1/n)`.

Comment: So what I want is to add the last two columns of this table to the original table:  `data %>% 
 count(state) %>% 
 mutate(state_rank = rank(1/n))`.

Comment: Espen's code (other answer) works, not sure if you there's a way to amend your approach to also work? New York should be ranked #1, Texas #2, etc (instead of 8, 7). And a short note about how `map_dbl` is doing the heavy lifting would be awesome.

Comment: Sure, you just need to run the rank on the reciprocal of the number of reviews (just as Espen did, then you get (almost) the same result. I updated the answer accordingly. You did not specify what you want to happen to rows that contain `NA` for the review. My code counts them, Espen's does not. Coincidentally, filtering them out leads to ties, meaning that one method will give ranks 1-7 on the sample data, while the other one gives ranks 1-8.

Comment: Regarding `map_dbl`: There's actually not much heavy lifting and no tricks here. `map_dbl` applies a function to each element of a vector or list separately. In our case the input is the column `books` of the outer tibble (which is itself a list of tibbles, containing the reviews per state) and the function applied is `1/nrow`. The result is just a vector containing the reciprocal of the number of reviews per state.